# How many LED can lights can I run on a single 20a breaker?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, recessed-lighting

I have 12/2 connected to a double 20amp breaker (only using one side of the breaker) running 9 can lights with Junco IC22W LED inserts.

How many more can lights can I attach to this system and is it okay to only use one side of a double 20amp breaker?

I'm trying not to cause a fire!

Comment: How many watts are your can lights?

Comment: The recessed unit is a juno ic22w. If that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to use 1/2 of a 2-pole 20A breaker.

Later, you can use the other 1/2 for an unrelated circuit.  Note that you must follow the breaker labeling as far as putting 2 wires on the screw. If needed, pigtail neutral.   This whole thing together is called a MWBC.

---

On the lights, you must look at each light and assume that future nitwits will put incandescent bulbs back in there.  Look at the largest incandescent light that is legal to put in that light - it may have a sticker that says "75W max".  (you're not responsible if they violate Code).  Total up all the max incandescent bulbs they're allowed to use (in watts).

Apply a 125% derate to that figure by multiplying it by 1.25.  So if your total was 1800 watts, x 1.25 = 2250  watts.

That number cannot exceed 2400 watts.  (20A x 120V).

Comment: For clarity, to make a MWBC out of the 2-pole breaker, the OP would need to use 12/3 wire and cannot simply run another rope of 12/2, correct?

Comment: @FreeMan You are mistaken.  No rule prevents hanging two /2s off a two-pole breaker.

Comment: You won’t see builders do it, because it defeats most of the points of using an MWBC: cheaper wire (four conductors worth of copper in a /3 vs. six in two /2s) and less labor to pull one cable instead of two. But it’s perfectly legal.

Comment: And, that's why I ask these follow up question - to learn things and correct my misunderstandings.

Comment: So if I doing this right, I have a max of 90w bulbs in each can. 90x number of cans and switches in the system. That number times 1.25 = total watts. That number needs to be less than 2400. Is that figuring the 80% rule as well?

Comment: @FreeMan what I propose there, it's only an MWBC for about 6 inches lol.

Comment: @Jay Sounds right. I get 21 but you only count actual loads... switches are free.  If you can get away from the legacy Edison socket, you can support a lot more lights.